# Inconveniente con envío de registro seleccionado entre formularios en C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo agradezco su colaboracion con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al trabajar con enlace de un registro de una grilla en C# Asp.net con un formulario

el código de enlace del campo Aspx, es el siguiente:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Código_alumno" >
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<% # Eval("codalumno") %>' 
  OnClick="lnk1_Onclick" CommandName="Select" > <%# Eval("codalumno") %> 
  </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

y el código C#, es el siguiente:

```
 public void lnk1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) // protected
 {
           string codalumno1 = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
            Response.Redirect("NotasAlumnos.aspx?codalumno1=" + codalumno1);
  }
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación ‘/’.
> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener mas información acerca del error y donde se origino en el código.

> Detalles de la excepción: System NullReferenceException. Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Error de código fuente:

`Línea 71:   GridView1.DataSource=dt;`

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Bueno... El error es claro. Intentas acceder a una propiedad, o un método de un objeto que no está instanciado o es null. Sabes si `GridView1` es null? O tal vez `dt` es null? pon un punto de interrupción y nos cuentas.

Comment: Cordial saludo Arriel, que pena responderte hasta ahora pues tenia otro error con esta aplicacion y otro en Php, pero en fin, en efecto depurando paso a paso por instrucciones llega un momento que la variable dt toma el valor de null, es decir dt es {}, y el Gridwiew toma el siguiente valor {System.web.UI.WebControl.Gridview} necesito saber por favor como podre arreglar ese inconveniente, Gracias anticipadas!.

Comment: Cordial saludo don Ariel, en el siguiente video envío mas explicado el inconveniente que se me presenta, un cordial saludo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5nJvzHrbxw